# Транскрипция слова "самое"

Tags: транскрипция

Слово **самое** [са-ма-й'э]. Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли?

Answer (score 1):

[са-мъ-й'ь] - вот верная транскрипция

Comment: По-настоящему верная транскрипция вообще с помощью МФА пишется

Answer (score 0):

Да, верная транскрипция.